# Adding nuget package in C# Interactive fails

Tags: c#, nuget, c#-interactive

I am trying to add a nuget package in C# Interactive in Visual Studio Code. Seems pretty straight forward, but it always fails.

```
#r "nuget:Newtonsoft.Json"
```

I always get back:

```
Error: PackageManagement Error 3217 Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
```

Same response for multiple packages.

Comment: [This GH thread](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/43918) suggests that you can't reference NuGet packages from the C# interactive REPL.

Comment: [This GH page](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/blob/main/docs/nuget-overview.md) shows it works. I get the same error trying to load "System.Text.Json".

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you are using Visual Studio *Code*. The command seems to work fine for me in a Polyglot Notebook. I assume that's what you're using? What version of Visual Studio Code are you using? What version of the "Polyglot Notebooks" extension do you have installed?

Comment: VS Code 1.64.0 and Polygot Notebooks 1.0.3103010